# IOS/SWIFT use gps ,internet and calculation on the background

Tags: ios, swift, gps

As a new iOS developer I am need to ask if it possible to run a background service on the phone when the application close and in this service to use user location, send the location to server and the return data compare to another data (for some calculation) and also send to the user Local Push Notification and all of this from the background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do all those things. Here's some info to start you off with location:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

and notifications:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

Both documents discuss how these things work in general, but also talk briefly about how they work in the background. Hopefully this gives you a jumping off point to find what you need.

Comment: Grate thank you so match I really appreciate your help but another one question about the subject and the most important is can I send or make something with this data in the Background after I get the location ?

Comment: I would assume so. Getting the information in the background isn't particularly useful if you can't do anything with it. I believe you can put calculations and functions into the location delegate to have them run when you get data. If you're sending the data over a network, you're going to want to request more background execution time.